# Enable different Handwriting Support for Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, language, handwriting

I have been told that Windows 7 Professional includes 8 additional handwritten support languages. How can I see what those languages are and how can I activate them?

I would need German and Japanese as additional languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I somehow found a solution.

As I didn't install SP1 yet, using Vistalizer I was able to install the RTM language packs for the languages I was looking for.

Edit: Sorry, the name is Vistalizator.